# Moving a point along a polynomial curve by certain arc length

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, curves, arc-length

Given a quadratic curve $y = ax^2+bx+c$ and a point $(n,y(n))$ on the curve, I need to find the coordinate of a new point $(m,y(m))$ on the curve and at certain arc distance $L$ from the original point $(n,y(n))$.
**Please note**, $L$ is not straight euclidean distance, it is, however, the curve segment length between two points.

I first tried to solve this using the arc length formula: The length $L$ of the quadratic arc segment between points $(n,y(n))$ and $(m,y(m))$ can be calculated as:
$$L = \int_n^m\sqrt{1+(b+2ax)^2}dx$$
Assuming that $n, a, b$ are known parameters, now the question is how to find a closed form equation for $m$ given the arc segment length $L$.

I tried to solve the integral and expand $L$:
$$L = \frac{-arsinh(2an+b)-(2an+b)\sqrt{4a^2n^2+4abn+b^2+1}}{4a}+\frac{arsinh(2am+b)+(2am+b)\sqrt{4a^2m^2+4abm+b^2+1}}{4a}$$

I am, however, not able to find an explicit solution to this equation for $m$.

I appreciate it if anyone could come up with a solution.

-- assumptions: $x,y$ can be positive or negative.

Comment: Even the much simpler equation $L=m+{\rm arcsinh}\ m$ can probably only be solved numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to solve for $m$ the equation
$$4a L+\sinh ^{-1}(2 a n+b)+(2 a n+b) \sqrt{1+(2 a n+b)^2}=$$ $$\sinh ^{-1}(2 a m+b)+\sqrt{1+(2 a m+b)^2} (2 a m+b)$$

Let $$k=4a L+\sinh ^{-1}(2 a n+b)+(2 a n+b) \sqrt{1+(2 a n+b)^2}$$ and $x=2am+b$ to make
$$k=\sinh ^{-1}(x)+x\sqrt{1+x^2} $$ This is an highly transcendental equation and,as @Gerry Myerson commented, a numerical method would be required (Newton method being the simplest) and, as usual, you need a starting guess (as good as possible if you want to reduce the number of iterations).

A reasonable approximation is
$$\sinh ^{-1}(x)+x\sqrt{1+x^2} \sim x^2\implies x_0=\sqrt k$$

Let us try with $a=3$, $b=5$, $n=7$ and $L=1234$ which give $k=14808+47 \sqrt{2210}+\sinh ^{-1}(47)$ which is $\approx 17022.$.

This would generate the following Newton iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 130.4685531 \\
 1 & 130.4453134 \\
 2 & 130.4453113
\end{array}
\right)$$ corresponding to $m=20.9075518$.

With this result, repeating the calculations, we get $L=1233.9999889$

Comment: Thanks for your detailed solution. I just have follow up questions. Getting back to the original question where we are asked to move a point along the curve - basically the point can be moved in two directions on the curve given a starting point. Is it true to say holding the constraint $m>n$ is required? I am trying to figure out if we can use the same approach to solve for $n$ if $m$ is known.